# Sentence generator wont execute online

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to run this Lisp code at [rextester.com](https://rextester.com/live/UAHI42557):

```lisp
;gnu clisp 2.49

(defun sentence () (append (Noun-phrase) (Verb-phrase)))
(defun Noun-phrase () (append (Article) (Noun)))
(defun Verb-phrase () (append (Verb) (Noun-phrase)))
(defun Article() (one-of '(the a)))
(defun Noun () (one-of '(man ball)))
(defun Verb () (one-of '(run hit took saw)))
(defun one-of (set)
  "Pick one element of set, and make a list of it"
  (list (random-elt set)))
(defun random-elt (choices)
  "Choose an element at a list at random"
  (elt choices (random (length choices))))
(sentence)
```

It executes but prints nothing.

See also the [original tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbiVRlwxix0).

Answer (score 2):

Runs just fine - you merely need to [`print`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) the result: replace

```
(sentence)
```

with

```
(print (sentence))
```

and you will see

```
(THE BALL TOOK THE MAN)
```

(always [the same](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes/faq.html#faq-random) despite `random`!)